# incorrect behavior of NSNumberFormatter on iPad in iOS

Tags: ios

This is my code

```
 NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
          NSNumber *myNumber = [formatter numberFromString:data._Item ];
    formatter.currencyCode = @"$";
```

For 6 digit number like  150000,the result on iPhone is 150,000 and on iPad it is 1,50,000.why comma is on wrong place on iPad.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Your question implies that you want to turn a number like 150000 into a string. But you code doesn't do that: it turns a string into a number. You need to decide what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of user preference on both devices. For your second formatter, namely `formatter`, you are using `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`, which would quite possibly take user preference, which could be set differently for both devices.

Comment: how to set it programmatically so that it should same for both devices

Comment: You can try with the `formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle `

Comment: no it is not still working i get different result for iPad and iPhone